# redirecting stdout to a file question?

Tags: c#, redirect, stdout

Hi why am I getting a access denied error when I try to execute this process?
I am running (MSBuild "projectfile here" "additional args") command with this new process

```
public bool CmdExecute(string command,string args)
     {



          bool isOk = true;
         try
         {
             using (System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
             {

                 proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                 proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                 proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                 proc.StartInfo.FileName = command;
                 proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;

                // Console.Out.WriteLine(proc.StartInfo.Arguments);

                 proc.Start();
                 string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
               proc.WaitForExit();
               Console.WriteLine(output);
             }

             }
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
             isOk = false;
         }
         return isOk;   
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs on Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput. You're not using it correctly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx

If you're using RedirectStandardOutput, you should be reading Process.StandardOutput and Process.StandardError and doing something with it.

I suspect that you're getting an access denied as your resulting command line doesn't make sense. You would get:

```
msbuild args &> P:\\build.txt
```

The extraneous ampersand (&) is going to cause problems.

Comment: Hi James thanks for the reply. I have modified my code and still get the access denied error(see above), it always goes to the catch. I noticed that when  proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute is true i dont get the access denied error, but redirectstandardouput needs it to be false. Please Help me i need the output of msbuild to be written to a file

Comment: UseShellExecute allows you to specify your command as "Foo.docx" and ShellExecute will look up the registered program for launching docx files. So you don't need that option. I would verify your working directory (which should probably be set to the location of the build file) as your build script might be trying to write to a path to which you don't have write access. You could also use ProcMon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find out which file your receiving access denied on if it isn't in your stack trace.

Comment: Hi Okay I have solved the access denied problem, and can now get standard outby redirecting it and using a streamwriter to write to file. But I got a follow up question for an alternative solution.

Is it possible to redirect the stdout of using redirect operators such as ">" or ">>" along with the arguments. Because I cant get it to work. The command will be executed but the file is not created.

example the command to be executed would be: 
msbuild c:\example.vbproj > build.log
When i i try it manually in the command line it works perfectly it can create the file. But with my program itwont?

Comment: The problem is that when you run it manually, your command shell (cmd.exe or powershell.exe) is parsing the command line and performing the redirection. When you use System.Diagnostics.Process, the Process object is launching the command and providing it with a list of arguments - including your command redirection. The shell is not involved and therefore can't perform the redirection. It might work if you set UseShellExecute=true. I haven't tried it.

Comment: I too was trying to run a messed-up command and ran into an access denied exception. I feel like slapping my forehead now, but thanks!